# linux rdp to EC2 windows machine - error "lost connection to the RDP server"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I created a simple EC2 instance (windows 2016), and without security group (all traffic allowed), and got public IP and DNS (created by the VPC).

Then I downloaded the rdp file from the EC2 in order to remote connect to the EC2, and got `"lost connection to the RDP server..."`.

I use my linux (fedora) machine, and use remmina to remote connect.

I'm new with AWS, am I missing something that I need to do before I connect?

P.S. I don't have IAM role, and also I didn't use the .pem file I downloaded - I don't know if it's related.

Comment: do you have a security group that allows the traffic in. i am confused because you said "without security group"

Comment: from your Fedora try telnet on rdp port `telnet YourPubliCIp 3389`. you should get `connected` as the output

Comment: @ArunK i don't have IAM role, I have security group.

Comment: @ArunK I did what you said - telnet for the public DNS, and got "Trying <public ip>..."

Comment: then allow port 3389 on the EC2 instance's security group

Comment: @ArunK i will try, but it's weird because i allowed all traffic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220245/discussion-between-arun-k-and-yagel).

Comment: can you try to ping to the instance. just to make sure that the problem is not rdp configuration inside the instance